# Use xpath instead of XSD object generation for accessing XML details?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xsd

There is an XML file hosted on a server that I want to parse. Normally I generate an XSD from the XML and then generate the java pojo's from this XSD. Using jackson I then parse the XML to a java object representation. Is it not more straightforward to just use xpath ? This means I do not need to generate a object hierarchy based on the XML and also I do not need to regenerate the object hierarchy if the XML changes. xpath seems much more concise and intuitive ?

Why should I use XSD , object generation instead of xpath ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema) specification XSD is used for defining the structure, content and semantics of XML documents. This means that you can use XSD to validate your XML file.

Depending on your circumstances you might be able to do without generating the whole object tree if all you need is to get some values from the XML file. In this case XPath is the way to go. However, you still might want to have an XSD file in order to validate the XML file before parsing it. This way you make your software [fail fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast), when the structure of your XML file changes, which will suggest that you change your XPath expressions. But for this to work, you shouldn't use the XSD you generate from your XML file, instead you should have a separate pre-generated XSD file which complies with the XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I think both approaches are valid, depending on the circumstances.
At the end of the day, you want to extract the values from that remote xml file and do something with them.

First criteria to consider is the size of that file, and the number of data elements.
If it's just a few, then xpath extraction should be straightforward. However, if that xml file represent a sizable and/or complex data structure, then you probably want the de-serialization to a Java data structure that you can then utilize, and JAXB would be a good candidate.

JAXB is going to be easier/better if the remote server adheres or publishes an XML Schema. If it doesn't, and changes often and significantly, you're going to suffer either way, but particularly so with JAXB. There are ways to smooth things over by pre-processing that xml with XSLT to force it into a more reliable form, but that is going to be a partial solution most likely.